# How to make Designer in Visual Studio generate component using parameterize constructor

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

How to make Visual Studio generate code using constructor with parameter?

For example:

When adding a ContextMenuStrip, this line of code is generated InitializeComponent() in MyForm.designer.cs

```
this.MyMenuStrip= new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(this.components);
```

Using dotPeek to reflect ContextMenuStrip doesn't give me any helpful way how I can do it.

I want to make a custom control that when it's dropped to any System.Windows.Forms.Control, the designer will call parameter constructor instead of parameter-less one.

Comment: How will it know what to pass for the parameter?

Comment: That's the good question. So how does it know it should pass this.components in ContextMenuStrip case?

Comment: Create your component in the form constructor manually with parameterized constructor

Comment: @Steve:Your direction is really helpful. You should make an answer so that I can mark it as an answer. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the MSDN page about the design-time features of Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164159.aspx#S7), it appears that a component with a constructor that takes an IContainer as a parameter is a special case:

> A component can let the designer know that it would like to be
>   notified when its container goes away by implementing a public
>   constructor that takes a single argument of type IContainer, as shown
>   in this snippet:

```
class ClockComponent : Component {
    public ClockComponent(IContainer container) { 
        // Add object to container's list so that 
        // we get notified when the container goes away container.Add(this); 
    } 
    // ...
}
```

> Notice that the constructor uses the container to add itself as a
>   container component. In the presence of this constructor, the designer
>   will generate code that uses this constructor, passing it a container
>   for the component to add itself to.

Also, see [Customizing Code Generation in the .NET Framework Visual Designers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973818.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Can you add this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973818.aspx to your answer? It would be very helpful for the other guys. Thank.

Comment: No problem, I added this and deleted my comments above before copying those links I posted! Ooops...